# Scheduled Tasks Infrastructure in Joomla 4.1

Tags: plugin, joomla-4.x, task

Is there documentation for the new Scheduled Tasks Infrastructure in Joomla 4.1 (https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/35143)?

I just created a test task for setting the site offline. I scheduled the interval to 5 minutes, but it does not run.[image]

The plugin "System - Schedule Runner" is published.

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [article](https://magazine.joomla.org/all-issues/march-2022/get-to-know-the-new-joomla-task-scheduler) on Joomla Magazine, may be it will helps you.

Comment: Including a link to a reputable source is fine, but it is preferable to write your specific advice here on this page (even if it is purely copy pasted). Sometimes links die or change and this can render a link-only answer to be useless.  Please [edit] your answer to explicitly state your guidance in resolving the question.